# Trying to build the power set function

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to build power set function.
When i build it as a generator it work fine.

But i want to write it as a regular function

```
def power_set(group):
    if len(group)==0:
        return set()
    else:
        last=group.pop()
        for sub in power_set(group):
            return (sub|{last})
            return (sub)
```

Anyone know what the problem could be ?

Comment: What exactly is it doing different? What do you want it to output, and what is it outputting?

Comment: Your second `return` statement never happens.

Comment: It's say that the sub isn't iterable, but it is a set. so i cant find what is the real error

Comment: @ChadS. Yes, this  is the different between the generator, i had the ability to continue from where I've stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to turn a generator into a function by trivially changing all `yield`s to `return`s. That will almost never work, as it completely changes the flow. A generator function will continue after a yield, but a return returns permanently.

In your case, you start by passing a large set into the `power_set()` function. It will happily recurse, with one less item each time, until it hits a single item. At that point the `pop()` statement will remove the last item, and it will then call `power_set()` with an empty set as input. This will return immediately as an empty set, causing the for loop to evaluate to:

```
for sub in set():
```

Since this is empty, it will skip the body of the `for` loop (the two `return`s) and reach the end of the function, thus by definition returning `None`. This causes your recursion stack to unroll one more level and try to execute:

```
for sub in None:
```

And that's the cause of the exception you're getting.

To fix it, you can't return one value at a time, but must return all values for a particular invocation of `power_set()` at once.

```
def power_set(group):
    if len(group)==0:
        return [set()]
    else:
        last=group.pop()
        s = []
        for sub in power_set(group):
            s.append(sub|{last})
            s.append(sub)
        return s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be lazy and just create a list that contains all the items produced by your generator version

```
powSet = list( power_set_generator(group) )
```

assuming `power_set_generator()` is your generator version that's working okay.